# How set up gradle on Mac

Tags: java, heroku, intellij-idea, gradle, web-deployment

Moved from Windows to MacOS (El Capitan) recently, so having troubles with compiling my project.

```
sh gradlew stage
```

outputs:

```
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
'radlew: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `{
'radlew: line 18: `warn ( ) {
```

I have installed IntelliJ Idea IDE, installed Java, do I have make any additional setup on MacOS?
My final target is deploy my project on Heroku, now I even can't compile project.. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Gradle Wrapper file, `gradlew`, is a bash script itself. You'd execute your Gradle command via `./gradlew stage`.

Comment: iMac-Alexey:RecipeSite alexeypapin$ ./gradlew stage
env: bash\r: No such file or directory

Comment: Does your project even provide a Wrapper script or why are you referring to `gradlew`?

Comment: Sorry, no idea about wrapper :/ Can you check it please at: https://github.com/zzheads/RecipeSite

Comment: 1. Your `gradlew` is missing the execution permission. Fix it via `chmod +x gradlew`. 2. You did not check in the Wrapper library `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar`. It is mandatory to have.

Comment: And after changed permissions same resulti                                           Mac-Alexey:RecipeSite alexeypapin$ chmod +x gradlew
iMac-Alexey:RecipeSite alexeypapin$ ./gradlew stage
env: bash\r: No such file or directory

Comment: Please delete all your Wrapper files and recreate them from scratch: `rm gradlew;rm gradlew.bat;rm -rf gradle;gradle wrapper`. There's also something wrong in your build script so you'll have to temporarily remove the following line: `apply plugin: 'spring-boot' `. BTW: Gradle 2.9 is old. You should use 3.0 right away.

Comment: Whoa, it works! Thanks, Benjamin! I don't understand about plugin 'spring-boot',  I need that plugin...

Comment: You can add the plugin again. It works for me. There was something messed up with your Wrapper. Make sure you commit and push all Wrapper files you generated.

Answer (score 0):

The gradle wrapper should work fine on OS X if you previously generated its files and checked them into your project properly.

Alternatively or even additionally, you can install the Mac version of  [gradle](http://braumeister.org/formula/gradle) on a system-level with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

**Install Homebrew:**

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

**Install gradle:**

```
brew install gradle
```